# Assigned VHDX disks not recognized as physical disks by guest

Tags: hyper-v

I have the following setup:

Host: Hyper-V on Windows 8.1
Guest: Windows Server 2012 R2

On the host, I assigned 4 VHDX files to the guest, where one holds the operating system:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VM -Name TEST-DC1 | Get-VMHardDiskDrive

VMName   ControllerType ControllerNumber ControllerLocation DiskNumber Path
------   -------------- ---------------- ------------------ ---------- ----
SOIL-DC1 SCSI           0                0                             C:\Hyper-V\TEST-DC1\... (127 GB)
SOIL-DC1 SCSI           0                2                             D:\TEMP\disk1.vhdx (110 GB)
SOIL-DC1 SCSI           0                3                             D:\TEMP\disk2.vhdx (120 GB)
SOIL-DC1 SCSI           0                4                             D:\TEMP\disk3.vhdx (130 GB)
```

Two of those disks (test-dc1.vhdx and disk1.vhdx) are correctly identified as physical disks:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PhysicalDisk

FriendlyName        CanPool             OperationalStatus   HealthStatus        Usage                              Size
------------        -------             -----------------   ------------        -----                              ----
PhysicalDisk0       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                      127 GB
PhysicalDisk1       True                OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                      110 GB
```

However, disk2.vhdx (120 GB) and disk3.vhdx (130 GB) are missing in the list. So I query for all disks and see the following:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Disk

Number Friendly Name                            OperationalStatus                    Total Size Partition Style
------ -------------                            -----------------                    ---------- ---------------
0      Microsoft virtueller Datenträger         Online                                   127 GB GPT
1      Microsoft virtueller Datenträger         Online                                   110 GB GPT
2      Microsoft virtueller Datenträger         Online                                   120 GB GPT
3      Microsoft virtueller Datenträger         Online                                   130 GB GPT
```

**I do not understand why disk2.vhdx and disk3.vhdx are not identified as physical disks. Please help me understand the problem here.**

Side note: I am preparing for 70-410, so this is no productive environment.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following theory: I did copy and paste the VHDX files. I assume there some kind of ID assigned to the files and that the disks have had that same ID. That must have confused the server. Once I recreated the VHDX files, the problem was gone.